# Restangular doesn't work with normal API structures

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am learning few AngularJS good supporting libraries like UI-routes and other stuffs. Today I started with Restangular `(https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).`

I feel good with the theory, but it accepts its own style of API URLs like the one mentioned below, which return the response in a square braces ( [] ) .

API:

https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/angularjs/collections/projects?apiKey=4f847ad3e4b08a2eed5f3b54

Full Demo:

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview&utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation)

We can not always depend on this restangular library as many of the API may not follow such structure unless there is a need to use square braces

Ex: FaceBook API, below image shown with API response which do not have [] at the beginning.

[image: Facebook API]

RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/angularjs/collections');

My question: Is Restangular can be used with any kind of API responses.

Answer (score 0):

yes, regarding the document here https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#restangular-methods

while method `.all(route)` expect response as **array** `[{}, {}, ..]`

the `.one(route, id)` or `get()` handle response as an object `{"what": "ever"}`